# ignorar cache em determinada pagina .php

Tags: php, cache

estou com um codigo php onde pego um link . so q esse link expira umas 10 vezes por dia, meu codigo verifica se o link expira e tras um novo.

```
//o arquivo é single.php wordpress
<video id="player" poster="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" controls style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
<source src="<?php echo $mp4;?>" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

a variavel que armazena a url é $mp4 , ela sempre traz o link correto

so que pra muitas pessoas que visitam o site aparece o link expirado, por conta do cache.

como fazer para esta pagina ou trecho de codigo nao entre em cache de maneira nenhuma?

detalhe. estou usando um plugin de cache para wordpress e cloudflare .

abraçaos

Comment: Coloque parte do código para facilitar entendimento do seu problema

Comment: editei no lugar certo agora... hehe

Answer (score -1):

Em uma versão resumida:

> Usando PHP:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```

> Usando HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Isso dirá ao navegador para sempre renovar o cache. Fazendo assim com que "nunca" tenha cache salvo para a página.

Reposta original em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas eu ja tentei isso e nao funcionou, sera que algo em htaccess n seria mais indicado? eu estou usando um plugin para cache wordpress e cloudflare.